# "police are" or "police is"

Tags: grammatical-number

In instructional videos I see on the internet, the teacher says "in the U.S and Canada, they automatically use police as plural noun", if it is already plural, then what's the singular of police?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Police* is a **plurale tantum**, a word with no singular form.

> The **police are** here.  　←　This is okay.
>   *A **police is** here. 　 　　←　This is not.

Most of the time, if you'd like to talk about a single officer of the law, you say *a police officer*, or just *an officer*:

> A **police officer** is here.　　←　　This is okay.
>   Several **officers** arrived.　　←　　This is also okay.

The latter sentence is fine if it's clear from context that you mean *a police officer*.

But in any case, you can't say **a police*.

---

*In this answer, the* * *symbol indicates that a phrase or sentence is ungrammatical.*

Comment: @MaulikV As well as a million slang terms. Some of which are highly offensive

Comment: @MaulikV "Policeman" is neither slang nor offensive. It's some of the other million slang terms that are offensive.

Comment: Just to confuse the issue, "The Police was an awesome band" is perfectly fine, but then I've turned it into a singular proper noun (the band named "The Police") instead of the standard dictionary definition for "police."

Answer (score 3):

When speaking of a particular police deparment/agency/service as a group, the singular form for the group will be something like "Police Department".

The police are coming through the door! 
versus 
The Police Department is hiring.

The actual term for a given police department is determined by the official name. For example, the Dallas Police Department or the University of Maryland Police Force.

Answer (score 1):

Snailplane's answer is fine. But since you are asking about the singular term for the word *police*, it's...

> [Policeman](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/policeman) - A male  police officer 
>   [Policewoman](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/policewoman) - A  female police officer.

So, as your title asks...

> *police are* - correct 
>   *a  <del>police</del> policeman/woman is* - correct

Comment: In English a policeman can be male or female because it refers to the race of man, not the gender.

Comment: If someone says "a policeman is coming," and it turns out that the officer is female, I will think that they made a mistake. I will think: "oh, it was actually a police<i>woman</i>." I am 30, male, middle class American from Houston, Texas (but Midwest linguistic heritage).

Comment: @njahnke If someone says "a policeman is coming" and a female officer shows up, I will think that they were using what they perceived as a generic term. Similar to saying "I will flag a waiter" and calling over a female waitress instead.

Comment: @JamesRyan I'm not sure about it! It's new to me if it is so.

Comment: The use of "man" (and the "-man" suffix) as a generic term *was*, certainly, common, and still does happen to a fair degree. The feminist movement has had wide success (at least, where I live, and apparently where @njahnke lives) in convincing a lot of the English-speaking population to move away from this habit, however. There are a number of people who consider it to be perpetuating a negative tradition, and a number of major style guides consider it invalid form. All that said, it may be more important to note that *policeman* is the singular form of *policemen*, **not** *police*.

Comment: Why the downvotes for this answer?

Comment: @RenéRoth Probably because it's wrong; *policeman* or *policewoman* is the singular form of *policemen* or *policewomen*, respectively, and not of *police*.

Comment: "Policeman" is a word, but from my experience only children use it. Adults would say "police officer", "officer", "cop", or maybe something else.

Comment: @KRyan I don't agree. Since the word *police* is an epicene, the singular term for that would be gender specific. If you dig in further, the opposite of police **may not** be police officer because *officer* there holds some authority and when we refer to a policeman, he can be someone with a very low designation in police department and cannot be referred to as an *officer*.

Comment: If someone told me, "A policeman is coming", and then a woman showed up, I would just assume he was using the word generically. I'd think nothing of it, unless maybe I had some reason to believe that the person knew which specific police officer was going to come.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama Hmm, I'm an adult and I say "policeman". I almost never say "police officer". Why waste breath on the extra syllables?

Comment: "policeman or policewoman is the singular form of policemen or policewomen, respectively, and not of police" Well, that's being awfully pedantic. If ten people from the police department show up, you say, "The police arrived." If one person shows up, you say, "A policeman arrived." It functions in practice as the singular for "police".