# "Human survival" vs " human's survival"

Tags: possessives

I found this:

> Fear is an essential attribute of human nature. It plays a crucial role in human survival.

But we cannot use:

> Fear is an essential attribute of human nature. It plays a crucial role in **human's** survival.

Why?

Comment: The answers on this other question might be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/86273/

Answer (score 4):

In the first sentence, the word [*human*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/human) is being used as an adjective.  What kind of survival?  *Human* survival, meaning the survival of humans in general.

In the second sentence, *human* must be a noun, because it has the [possessive **'s**](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/), and only nouns and proper names can use that.  But this causes a problem: *human* is a [count noun](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/noncount.htm), so you can't just say "human's survival", you need an article, like **a** human's survival, or **this** human's survival.  Using *human* as a noun also changes the meaning of the sentence, because now you're not talking about the survival of humans as a general concept, but the survival of one particular human.

Another way you could phrase it is

> It plays a crucial role in **humans'** survival.

This sentence uses *humans* as the plural noun, so it can still take the possessive, but it means "the survival of all humans".  When you make the possessive of a plural noun that ends in **s**, you just add **'**, not **'s**.