# January's schedule vs. January schedule

Tags: difference, punctuation, possessives, apostrophe, attributives

Is it **January's schedule** or **January schedule**?

I also get confused with whether to include an apostrophe before "bill."

This is my **January bill** or **January's bill**.

Comment: Google shows error and recommends using 'January schedule' instead of 'January's schedule'.

Comment: Related: [“the police conspiracy” vs. “the police's conspiracy”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/86273/9161)

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh And Google's [Ngram Viewer finds no results for "January's schedule"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=January+schedule%2CJanuary%27s+schedule&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=0), but many results for "January schedule". Grammar checkers are notoriously inaccurate because what is correct in a particular instance is very dependent on the context. It's much more complex than "January's X" is always preferred over "January X".

Comment: True. I looked in the Google Ngram for finding relevant results. When I found none, I thought of not linking it, since it will be pretty useless.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh My point is that Google saying it is an error is just as useless.

Comment: Agreed! Always not so reliable. But not an issue. I got to know the correct use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct and idiomatic.

Your choice depends on the construction:

**January's schedule is likely to be busy.**

Here January is used with a possessive apostrophe, as in **winter's cold**.

or

**The January schedule this year is likely to be busy.**

Here January is used as an attributive or adjectival noun to modify schedule, as in **winter clothing** or **history lesson**.

Which you prefer to use just depends on the context and your preferences.

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm